# Sould I .gitignore build output for a WordPress plugin?

Tags: git, wordpress

Our builds are not binary by nature of WordPress PHP/JS, merely combined and minified. But they can be re-created by any developer easily and I feel like they shouldn't be version controlled but I thought I'd ask. What's the best practice? If they were version controlled I assume we'd waste some time with conflicts from the build output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your feeling is correct: In general, do not check output files into source control.

There are exceptions, e.g. when a tool generates an initial template that you then edit by hand.